# Allow users to sign in using their username or email address with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

## Problem

I followed the [tutorial on Devise's Wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) and now my login page is broken. I continually get an error saying 'Invalid Email or Password.' Neither user_name nor email work for logging in.

Note: My user name field is `user_name` not `username` like in the tutorial.

Did I miss something? Type something wrong? For the most part I cut and paste.

## Code

Application Controller:

```
## app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) 
            { |u| u.permit( :email, :birthday, :password,:password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) 
            { |u| u.permit( :login, :user_name, :email, :password, :remember_me ) }
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) 
            { |u| u.permit( :first_name, :last_name, :user_name, :birthday, 
                            :address_1, :address_2, :city, :state, :zip_code, 
                            :facebook, :twitter, :google_plus, :instagram, :pinterest ) }
    end

end
```

User Model:

```
## app/models/user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise  :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    validates :birthday, :presence => true
    validates :user_name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

    # Virtual attribute for authenticating by either user_name or email
    # This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'user_name'
    attr_accessor :login

    def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions.to_h).where(["lower(user_name) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      else
        where(conditions.to_h).first
      end
    end

end
```

Devise Initializer (uncommented and changed only this line):

```
## app/config/initializers/devise.rb

config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
```

Login View:

```
## app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

<% @title="Login" %>

<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <%= f.alert_message "Please fix the errors below." %>

    <%= f.text_field :login, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.primary "Log In" %>

<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Devise's Error Labels (didn't need to change as I have these lines):

```
## app/config/locales/devise.en.yml

invalid: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
...
not_found_in_database: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

## Update to question

## Versions Used

Ruby: ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

Rails: Rails 4.2.0

Devise 3.4.1

## New ApplicationController Code

James Milani provided the answer in that I forgot to restart my server. But, once I did do that, the ApplicationController Code started to error providing 2 errors repeated 3 times.

```
/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:51: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}' { |u| u.permit( :email, :birthda... ^
/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:51: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

I changed the Application Controller like so and the errors went away and everything works:

```
## app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :birthday
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :login
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :first_name
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :last_name
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :user_name
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :birthday
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :address_1
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :address_2
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :city
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :state
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :zip_code
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :facebook
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :twitter
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :google_plus
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :instagram
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :pinterest
    end

end
```

Now, why the other code doesn't work, I do not know, but that is for another question. As of now, this question is answered. I have just updated this section in case someone else has the same question or issue later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a pass through your code--looks good; if I had 50 or more rep this would be a comment, but you did restart your server, right? Otherwise that initializer won't come into effect. Maybe that's it?

Comment: Also, what version of Rails are you using? Is it Rails 4? If so, the tutorial says to use to_hash instead of to_h for the model code. :-)

Comment: I have updated my question with the versions. I am using Rails 4 and you are absolutely right. I forgot to restart my server... of all the things. Thank you. It is working now.

Comment: I also had to change the ApplicationController code because the code from the tutorial caused my app to error after I restarted the server. The updated code I am now using, which does not cause errors and allows the user to sign in with both a user name or an email, is in my question above.